# Change a filename migration with Flyway

Tags: database, migration, flyway

I need to rename a Flyway migration file. I've already applied the migration on my local database.

How can I drop or reset my local postgres database to not have the Flyway migration exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the database, issue this command:

```
drop database testdb;
```

Then:

```
create database testdb;
```

If you don't want to go that far, and you want to bypass your server error, do this:

```
update schema_version set description = '', script = '', checksum = '' where version = '';
```

Then restart your server.